# Why 'is' operator doesn't work with generic type parameter?

Tags: c#

Background: I write a generic method that finds and returns an object of a particular type specified by a generic type parameter from a collection.

I discover that for some reason 'is' operator returns 'false' even if a type of an object and a type that I pass as a generic type parameter are the same.

```
public abstract class AbstractComponent { }
public class Component : AbstractComponent { }

//Collection
public List<AbstractComponent> Components = new List<AbstractComponent> { new Component() };

//Method
public ComponentType GetComponent<ComponentType>()
{
    foreach (var component in Components)
    {
        var type = component.GetType();
        var eq = type is ComponentType; // false
        var eq2 = type == typeof(ComponentType); // true
        var eq3 = Type.Equals(type, typeof(ComponentType)); // true

        //Updated
        var eq4 = component is ComponentType; // also true, thanks for that
    }
    return default(ComponentType);
}

//Method invocation
var Component = GetComponent<Component>();
```

I will use some other way, but I want to know why exactly this behavior occurs. Can someone explain this, please?

Comment: becuse `type` is `Type` not `ComponentType`

Comment: I think you're looking for `if (component is ComponentType)`. (I'd also recommend renaming that to `TComponent` to follow normal .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`type` isn't an instance of `ComponentType` it is an instance of `Type` so `is` won't work.

Think you want [IsAssignableFrom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignablefrom?view=netframework-4.8) e.g.

```cs
typeof(ComponentType).IsAssignableFrom(type)
```